# How to print numbers from 1-100 incremented by 5

Tags: c

I am trying to print numbers from 1-100 incremented by 5. This is my code:

```
printf( "Exercise 1" ); 

int number = 0; 

for ( number = 0; number <= 100; number + 5 ){
    printf( "%d", number );
}
```

Do you know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: That should be `number += 5` or `number= number + 5` That part of the for statement must increment the controle variable and requires assignment of the incremented value to the control variable..

Comment: start with `number = 1` and `number += 5`

Comment: When asking a question like this, always state what your program is doing and what you want it to be doing instead, with an example. Your title asks about numbers from 1 to 100, but your code starts with `number` set to 0. This leaves us unsure whether you want the output to be “1 6 11 16…” or “0 5 10 15…”. An example would clear that up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.

```
for ( number = 0; number <= 100; number +=5 )
```

Comment: Tip: Your answer is correct but it would be nice with some explanation together with the solution. A good explanation (i.e. what is the problem with OPs code?) will also increase the chance of being upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the documentation of a `for` loop from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)...

> `for (initialization; condition; increase) statement;`
>
> Like the while-loop, this loop repeats statement while condition is
>   true. But, in addition, the for loop provides specific locations to
>   contain an initialization and an increase expression, executed before
>   the loop begins the first time, and after each iteration,
>   respectively. Therefore, it is especially useful to use counter
>   variables as condition.
>
> It works in the following way:
>
> 1. ***initialization*** is executed. Generally, this declares a counter variable, and sets it to some initial value. This is executed
>      a single time, at the beginning of the loop.
> 2. ***condition*** is checked. If it is true, the loop continues; otherwise, the loop ends, and statement is skipped, going directly to
>      step 5.
> 3. ***statement*** is executed. As usual, it can be either a single statement or a block enclosed in curly braces { }.
> 4. ***increase*** is executed, and the loop gets back to step 2.
> 5. the loop ends: execution continues by the next statement after it.

You had most of this right.. except the last parameter...

In your specific piece of code, that last piece of your `for` loop, `number + 5`, you need to increase your loop counter and assign it back to itself (assignment)

You can accomplish this two ways:

1. `number = number + 5`
2. `number += 5` Since you are reassigning the same variable with it's own value plus a number, C has some built in "shortcuts" (assignment operators).

Both of these statements are equivalent, but note the better readability of list item 2.